# misuse central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

The central limit theorem can be stated as follow:

$$\overline{X}\overset{d}{\rightarrow}N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty\\
Z=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\overset{d}{\rightarrow}N(0,1)\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty
$$

[CLT](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/27/27.1)

However, I also spot a statement from the text

*Arak M. Mathai, Hans J. Haubold-Probability and Statistics*:

---

*The importance of this limit theorem is that whatever be the population, whether
discrete or continuous, the standardized sample mean will go to a standard normal
when $n\to\infty$ and when the population variance is finite. Thus the normal or Gaussian distribution becomes a very important distribution in statistical analysis. Misuses
come from interpreting this limit theorem in terms of $\bar{x}-\mu$ or $\bar{x}$. This limit theorem does not imply that $\bar{x}-\mu\sim N(0,\sigma^2/n)$ for large n. It does not imply that $\bar{x}\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ for large n*

The textbook only admits the standardized form

I am wondering which one is more accurate, and why does the second graph say so?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question will be closed soon unless you replace the images with normal text/Mathjax.

Comment: The start of the second quotation seems to be an attempt to put the first quotation into words.  The final part of the second quotation seems to be saying convergence in distribution in the limit is not the same thing as having the same distribution when $n$ is finite

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your reply. Yes, convergence in the distribution in the limit is more like a theoretical concept, strictly speaking, they are different things. But when $n>50$ is large, is it ok to employ that different forms $(\bar{x}-\mu)\to N(0,\sigma^2/n)$ of normal distribution

Comment: It is easy enough to find a counterexample for any fixed $n$:  suppose there is a lottery, and you have probability $0.001$ of winning $1000$ and probability $0.999$ of winning $0$.  The expected average win is $1$ but the distribution of the average of $100$ attempts is not at all normally distributed (the most likely sample mean is $0$ and the second most likely sample mean is $10$)

Comment: @Henry I agree with your example. But, aren't we expecting the $100$ attempts has the normal distribution if these $100$ attempts get a sufficiently large number of trials? your example only has $2$ trials. I just wanna make sure if I understand CLT correctly.

Comment: My example has $100$ trials (two possible outcomes per trial, $101$ possible averages over the trials).  $\mathbb P(\bar X_{100}=0)\approx 0.9048$, $\mathbb P(\bar X_{100}=10)\approx 0.0906$, $\mathbb P(\bar X_{100}=20)\approx 0.0045$, $\mathbb P(\bar X_{100}=30)\approx 0.0001$, etc. with $\mathbb E[\bar X_{100}]=1$.  It is a scaled binomial distribution, but so extreme than you need a much bigger number of trials to get a normal approximation, and I could find a similar counter example for that bigger number of trials.